# create spreadsheet using gsheet api and gdrive api using python

Tags: python-3.x, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

- I want to create new Spreadsheet in the specific folder.
- I want to achieve this using google-api-python-client with python.
- using gdrive and gsheet api

I achieved the above but unfortunately I am not able to understand where did i create the file. my folder has the access of the service account , but when i try to open the file using the id , it opens up for request access and Im confused which access should be provided. I guess its something simple and I missed it.

```
service = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)
drive_service = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials, cache_discovery=False)
folder_id = "folder_id"
        file_metadata = {
            'name': 'sampleName-test1',
            'parents': folder_id,
            'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet',
        }
        res = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata,fields='id').execute()
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your current issue and your goal from `I achieved the above but unfortunately I am not able to understand where did i create the file. my folder has the access of the service account , but when i try to open the file using the id , it opens up for request access and Im confused which access should be provided. I guess its something simple and I missed it.`. Can I ask you about the detail of them?

Comment: sure, I wasnt so clear regarding what I achieved. My requirement was to create a spreadsheet in gdrive using the API, which the above code runs without any error, but I have no clue where is the file being created. I have a drive account and a service account, where the drive account has the access to the service account.please let me know if i was clear @Tanaike

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your script, I think that `'parents': folder_id,` should be `'parents': [folder_id],`. And, in your situation, who is the owner of the folder of `folder_id = "folder_id"`? If the owner is the service account, how about sharing it with your Google account? By this, you can see it in your Google Drive as "shared with me". If you are the owner, I think that you can see the created Spreadsheet in the folder in your Google Drive. How about this?

Comment: thank you @Tanaike, i missed the brackets

Comment: Thank you for replying. If your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

'parents': folder_id, should be 'parents': [folder_id]